# Rename R data frame column names based on string extract of values

Tags: r

I'm working with semi-structured wiki data from a project I inherited from a colleague and having some trouble getting it tidy. It has a ton of issues but one of the first things I need to do is create sensible column names.

Suppose I have a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(x1 = "ID: 4",
    x2 = "Start Date: 1946/11/13",
    x3 = "End Date: 1946/12/31")
```

```
 x1                     x2                   x3
ID: 4 Start Date: 1946/11/13 End Date: 1946/12/31
```

I'd like to extract everything in the value before the colon and rename the columns based on this extract so that my data frame looks like this:

```
ID Start_Date End_Date
4  1946/11/13 1946/12/31
```

So far, I've learned that I can use str_extract from from the stringr package to pull out the strings of interest but I'm stumbling over how to use this resulting list for renaming column names.

```
library(tidyverse)

map(df, function(x) {str_extract(x,"[^:]+") %>% str_replace(" ", "_")})
```

Thanks for checking out this question :)

Comment: Do you have one row only or multiple rows?

Comment: @M-- The actual data will have multiple rows but the strings preceding the colon (i.e. id, start_date, etc.) shouldn't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a little regular expression magic to grab anything that appears before the ":" character, then assign the results to the column names of your data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(x1 = "ID: 4",
                 x2 = "Start Date: 1946/11/13",
                 x3 = "End Date: 1946/12/31")

labels <- sapply(df[1, ], sub, pattern = '(?=:).*', replacement = '\\1', perl = T)
labels <- gsub(' ', '_', labels)
colnames(df) <- labels

> colnames(df)
[1] "ID"         "Start_Date" "End_Date"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
nm = gsub("\\s", "_", sapply(df[1,], function(x) gsub("(.*):.*", "\\1", x)))
setNames(data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) gsub(".*:\\s?(.*)", "\\1", x))), nm)
#  ID Start_Date   End_Date
#1  4 1946/11/13 1946/12/31
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame(x1 = "ID: 4",
                 x2 = "Start Date: 1946/11/13",
                 x3 = "End Date: 1946/12/31", stringsAsFactors = F)

names(df) <- sapply(df[1,], function(x) {stringr::str_extract(x,"[^:]+") %>% stringr::str_replace(" ", "_")})
df <- rbind(df, sapply(df[1,], function(x) {stringr::str_extract(x,":.+$") %>% stringr::str_replace(": ", "")}))
df <- df[2, ]
```